# Efficient Firebase document reading and querying with hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am currently using queries to get the initial state of a user. They potentially could have thousands of individual documents that don't need to be set up via hooks.

My current approach is mostly working, however it does mean there is a double read on the documents that I create the hook on.

```
query(
     collection(firestore, "userDocs"),
     where("ownedBy", "==", userId),
     orderBy(documentId()),
     limit(6)
     )
```

This is my initial query, I am using react infinite scrolling to then fetch more as they scroll down. Each of these documents is a rendered component in React.

Within that component I then setup a hook to pretty much go and get the same data that I just did.

```
setCol(doc(firestore, "userDocs", userDocId),{
        snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      })
```

They both set a document state on the component, once on load, and when ever the firebase hook goes off. I am using a react firebase package here for hook simplification.

My question is, how can I get this hook functionality which I really need, but stop this initial read from the firebase hook. If I don't do the initial query for the documents, I don't get the data I need to make the hooks. And also an approach I tried of just using hooks passed to the user doc component was much slower than my query based approach because firebase queries are really fast than singular document reads.

I am basically trying to prevent a second read when the hook on the document is created because its data will just be the data I got back from the query and isn't very efficient. I have seen some implementations that get around this using a timestamp updated at field, but does that require me to perform an extra write on the documents that I've just queried?

When I update the document that triggers the hook its possible I can pop a timestamp field in then but Im not sure how that solves my initial read problem.

Many thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible code including the imports? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @ChristianPaulAndaya, I suppose this is more of a process problem regardless of code. I have already read a document, I only want to them update the document if there is a change. How do I prevent the duplicate read that happens when I setup the document listener. Hope that helps :)

Comment: You may want to maintain a cache as individual documents are added, removed, and modified. You may check this documentation for [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)